# Ransomware [supportcrypt2019@cock.li].Adame

Tags: windows, encryption, virus, malware

Today I have turned on my pc and I found out that all my files in all my 5 Internal Harddrives and usbkey attached have been encrypted.

The extension is [supportcrypt2019@cock.li].Adame

Is there a way to get all my files back?

Comment: Sorry to hear this, it really depends on; A. If the files have actually been encrypted, there are a number of more basic ransomeware copy cat applications that simple rename file extensions so you think the file has been encrypted. B. If the files have genuinenly been encrypted, then the options are: a) Hopefully a security vendor has released a tool to decrypt them based on errors really in the ransomeware. E.g. https://success.trendmicro.com/solution/1114221-downloading-and-using-the-trend-micro-ransomware-file-decryptor. b) You pay the ransome and hope you get the keys to unlock your files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit) & please **don't** ever pay up. Often the malware was bought by wannabe script kiddies after a quick buck & they have no idea how to decrypt their own work. Even if successful, you're paying criminals to continue their crime.